# Creating and writing GeoPackage Lookup Tables

Tags: ogr, geopackage, sqlite

I am writing Python using OGR to create and write a single vector layer in a GeoPackage. Some of the feature attributes need to be foreign keys to several lookup tables. My needs are completely standard SQLite capability.

Is it required or recommended that I use the same OGR driver that I use for the feature layer to create and write to the lookup tables or can I use a native Python SQLite3 connection?

Comment: Read about spatial views https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#vector-gpkg and consider if they could be suitable for your use case.